# Replace class of a div using removeClass and addClass

Tags: php, jquery, addclass, removeclass

For my new wordpress site I need some help. I got 4 pages and 2 different sidebars. On 2 pages there shouldn't be a `border-left` and on the other 2 pages there should be a `border-left`. So I got following code:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
        <?php if(is_page('Willkommen') || is_page('Angebot'))
            {
                dynamic_sidebar('Angebot');
            }

            else
            {
                dynamic_sidebar('Anfahrt');
                if(is_page('Anfahrt'))
                {
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
function removeBorder()
{
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if($('#sidebar').hasClass('sidebar'))
        {
            $(this).removeClass('sidebar')
            $(this).addClass('secondsidebar')
        }

    });
}
</script>";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div><!-- sidebar -->
```

I want to remove the class "sidebar" and add the class "secondsidebar" if there is a `div#sidebar` on the page. But the code won't work. I wrote this code for myself and I'm a beginner in jQuery :) So please be patient.

I hope someone can give me a hint.

Cheers

Comment: You define a function `removeBorder` here, but never call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A pure PHP solution should be possible as well.**

```
<div id="sidebar" class="<?php if (is_page('Anfahrt')) : ?>secondsidebar<?php else : ?>sidebar<?php endif; ?>">
    <?php
    if (is_page('Willkommen') || is_page('Angebot')) {
        dynamic_sidebar('Angebot');
    }

    else {
        dynamic_sidebar('Anfahrt');
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

NOTE: try not to use IDs and classes with the same name. `#sidebar` and `.sidebar` might get confusing.

Explanation for the classes:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="<?php if (is_page('Anfahrt')) : ?>secondsidebar<?php else : ?>sidebar<?php endif; ?>">
```

When the server reads this (PHP is code that is executed *by the server* before rendering the result back to the user) it comes to "class" and it notices an if-statement. "what text should I put in the `class=""` of this element?" The server then sees the instructions:

- If the page is "Anfahrt": the text to return should be `secondsidebar`
- Else (*in all other cases*): the text should be `sidebar`

"Text" isn't really a good name here. But you get what I mean. This "text" is then placed where the if-statement is. The result then is (as it is returned to a user):

If the page is "Anfahrt":

```
<div id="sidebar" class="secondsidebar">
```

If the page is anything else:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
```

Comment: Hm okay. Yeah it make sense. But it still doesn't replace the class "sidebar" with "secondsidebar"

Comment: Yeah I looked at your edit and I will thank you for explaining this so nice, but it still doesn't work. If I visit page "Anfahrt" it doesn't replace the class "sidebar" with "secondsidebar" :/ Is still something wrong?

Comment: @Sergio Look closely, it isn't inside the function anymore. The first part was, the result doesn't.

Comment: Aaaaaah nice! It works now! Thank you. But: Can you explain it a little bit closer to me? Because I don't want to have a code that I don't understand :)

Comment: Ah yeah that sounds logical :) But for someone who has never looked closer to PHP it isn't as simple as it seems to write something like this :) Thank you for your help and support and for the very nice explanation :) (Y)

Comment: Good idea to go with php. +1